# How can I select comma but if it with another, exclude in regex

Tags: regex

I would like to make JSON formatter
want to select comma in JSON
and also want to deselect if comma with bracket

```
{
  "name":"s1",  << select comma
},{             << deselect comma
  "name":"s2",  << select comma
}
```

How can I with regex?

Comment: Please learn how to use a JSON parser, with whatever language/tool you are using.  Regex is not the best choice for parsing JSON.

Comment: I need shorten row only for display. Thanks for your advice anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use negative lookahead:
`,(?!{)`

1. `,` - comma
2. `(?!{)` - not followed by bracket